# How can one require a record type filtered dependent picklist in Screen Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, dependent-picklist, screen-flow, required

I need to make a non-required dependent picklist filtered by record type, required on a Screen Flow page.
Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe what I want to do is currently impossible without code.

Salesforce provides 2 ways of representing a dependent picklist in Screen Flow.
Both of which have their limitations.

1. **Dependent Picklists Component**
   You can drag and drop from the list of components.
   HOWEVER, it will never filter the values based on Record Type.
2. **Record Field**
   You can drag and drop from the list of the newish record fields tab.
   HOWEVER, it is not possible to alter any of the fields standard settings.
   For example, in my org the fields are not required, therefore I cannot make them required on the Screen.

There wasn't anything from unofficial sf or appexchange that I could find to fix this.
If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: see https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2022/02/15/flow-screen-component-dependent-picklist-with-record-types-support-version-2/

Comment: @cropredy I installed and tried it, there's no option of making the field required.

Comment: raise an issue on the developer's Github repo; perhaps others will have ideas on how to solve your issue (you can also check out the OhanaSlack workspace that has lots of people with Flow experience)

Answer (score 0):

Although not an ideal solution, you can also enforce mandatory fields using Decision elements within the flow. After the screen you can check whether a value has been set, and if not return the user the previous screen with an error message showing.

One note with this way of enforcing values is that if you have other validation on the screen, the decision check fires after the user has navigated so it's sub-optimal from a user-experience perspective as there is a chance that don't know about this error until after they've addressed others.